# How can I create a carousel?

Tags: android

I looked for answers on this, but I can not find an example that could help me. I am looking to do a carouselle of this form can finger-scroll with arrows.

[image]

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can use this project to get started:

http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/

You can adjust the angle at which things are displayed, opacity, etc.

Comment: ??? I'm trying to do something with your link, but i can't manage to do what I want ..., for instance, changing the disposition of imageViews

Comment: you mean the angle? look at the top of the CoverFlow class, mMaxRotationAngle

Comment: yes, i already work on that, ... When i put the mMaxRotationAngle to 0, my imageViews are flat but, the last imageview is over the previous ...I understand why but i don't know how making the trick.

Comment: look for setSpacing in CoverFlow.java

Comment: okey, the spacing is reduced, but image view in the foreground is overlapped by the following